# vscode's first extension tutorial: command not listed/breakpoints not hit

Tags: vscode-extensions, yo

#### Problem description

I followed the [vscode tutorial on creating an extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension),
but I cannot reproduce the behavior of "the command popping up in the Command Palette", nor can I get breakpoints to hit.

#### My steps

- I followed the tutorial verbatim, that is

  - `yo code`
  - `New Extenion (TypeScript)`
  - ...
  - all the way to package manager: `npm`
- Open the project with `code`
- Press <kbd>F5</kbd> (let's ignore the small error that I got that there's no problem matcher installed. It went away after installing the recommended extensions (`eamodio/vscode-tsl-problem-matcher` and `Microsoft/vscode-eslint`).
- The Extension host pops up. There's no error.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>

Unfortunately the command `hello world` doesn't pop up in the list.
Neither are the breakpoints hit in `extension.ts` (like in [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension#debugging-the-extension) part of the tutorial).
The breakpoints are unhittable, i.e. their interior is white rather than red.
It seems the extension is not being loaded. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

#### What I tried

I retried many attempts, triple checking my spellings and following of the tutorial. I tried a PC restart. I tried with and without webpack bundling. I reran `tsc`. I downgraded typescript to 4.7.4 (as later on it warns that 4.8.2 isn't officially supported)

Some possibly relevant version numbers:
Windows 10,
npm 8.5.5,
yo 4.3.0,
vscode 1.69.2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Check the version of `engines.vscode` in `package.json`:

The template generated by `yo` requires the latest vscode the be installed. Change it in the `package.json` or upgrade vscode.

#### More detailed explanation

I diagnosed the issue by compiling the extension into a VSIX (`npm install -g vsce && vsce package`).
After installing it, I expect the command to be listed in the Command Palette, but don't expect the breakpoint to be hit.

Upon manually installing the vsix in the Extension development host (extensions -> triple dot -> Install from VSIX), vscode prompted the error

> Unable to install extension `undefined.hello-world` as it is not compatible with VSCode version 1.69.2

That gives a hint. In the `package.json` there was

```json
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.70.0"
  },
```

but that version is higher than I currently have installed. After changing that to my version, everything started working as advertised.

Comment: Really a lifesaver! I can't thank you enough for this.

Comment: Just for clarification purposes: you can check your VSCode version by going to Help > About (inside VSCode). And then, you'll see the current version (e.g: 1.83.1), that's the number you need to put in package.json > engines.vscode